# assembly language printing garbage value while using functions in boot sector

Tags: assembly, nasm, boot

Hello I am just trying to print 2 messages using functions in assembly language (A simple boot-sector program ), This is my code:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx,HELLO_MSG
call printer 


mov bx,GOODBYE_MSG
call printer


jmp $

printer:
        pusha
        mov ah,0x0e
        mov al,bl
        int 0x10
        popa 
        ret




HELLO_MSG:
     db 'Hello, World',0

GOODBYE_MSG:
     db 'Bye User',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0 
dw 0xaa55
```

I dont know where I am going wrong but the above program is printing some garbage value. Can someone help me out with this please??

Comment: Try to set up the segment registers before attempting to refer to values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `AL` expects a character to be printed, but you give it a low byte of a pointer to memory address where the first byte of text is stored.

Second, Function 0x0e prints one character in `AL` only, so to print the whole string you should iterate through it.

Third, `BX` is not the best register to store string pointer. Better use `SI`.

Having all that,

```
  pusha
  mov ah, 0x0e
__continue:
  mov al, [si]
  inc si
  test al, al    ; terminating null reached?
  jz __ret       ; yes, exit
  int 0x10
  jmp __continue
__ret:
  popa
  ret
```

`mov al, [si] / inc si` can be changed to `lodsb` for smaller code size

Comment: ThankYou and what does si stand for??

Comment: SI is just another general-purpose register (Source Index register). Together with DI (Destination Index) it is used for addressing source and destination operands in some instructions like `LODSB`. You should definitely spend some time on theory ;)

Comment: do you know any good book or source?? it will be really helpfull

Comment: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html is a must have reference to instructions.   Can't give advice on any books for beginners. sorry.

Comment: Also Ralf Brown's Interrupts list http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm will be helpful to you in real mode. `Int 16h` for keyboard, `Int 13h` for disks, `Int 10h` for display to start with

Comment: THanks it was really helpful